# getCity/state from IP address using PHP

Tags: php, geoip

I am working on a client project, where he needs the city/state of the user by taking his ip address.

1) he has purchased maxmind GeoIP2 Precision, but no idea how to implement the code in php. documentation says some instruction to download composer.exe, when i downloaded it, it is asking me to download php.exe then after download php.exe, i tried to install composer.exe then it tried to install composer.phar and gave me this error

"Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly. Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl "

Please suggest me the easiest way to get the city/state from IP address using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: use php5, php5-geoip with linux environment. If you have linux server, you can resolve this task in short time

Comment: yes, it is hosted on linux server, Please advice me further what needs to do..

Comment: that linux are you use? ubuntu? centos? redhat? debian?

Comment: if you are running unix, you will need to use `httpd` as a webserver, with the `php` plugin. The above mentioned `.exe` files are for windows only.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This API will get your location details.  Try this

```
    <?php
    $ip = '168.192.0.1'; // your ip address here
    $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    if($query && $query['status'] == 'success')
    {
        echo 'Your City is ' . $query['city'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Your State is ' . $query['region'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Your Zipcode is ' . $query['zip'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Your Coordinates are ' . $query['lat'] . ', ' . $query['lon'];
    }
    ?>
```

Here are the outputs you can use.  Call them using the key;

```
    <?php
    array (
      'status' => 'success',
      'country' => 'COUNTRY',
      'countryCode' => 'COUNTRY CODE',
      'region' => 'REGION CODE',
      'regionName' => 'REGION NAME',
      'city' => 'CITY',
      'zip' => 'ZIP CODE',
      'lat' => 'LATITUDE',
      'lon' => 'LONGITUDE',
      'timezone' => 'TIME ZONE',
      'isp' => 'ISP NAME',
      'org' => 'ORGANIZATION NAME',
      'as' => 'AS NUMBER / NAME',
      'query' => 'IP ADDRESS USED FOR QUERY',
    );
    ?>
```

This will not be reliable for mobile.  If you are on mobile, you can use the following javascript

```
    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    </script>
```

This will use the gps built in to the device and get the cordinates.  Then you can cross reference with a database filled with cords. (thats one option, and thats what i do).

You can find a city lat lng databases online if you search and if thats what you chose to do for mobile.

Comment: wow, you rocked man, thanks ..it really worked, will it work for all over the cities in the world ??

Comment: Yes I believe it should.  But if you use mobile it will not be reliable.  If you use mobile, there are other methods for that

Comment: Oh really, i will save this code for my future projects also, can you let me know for the mobile also..

Comment: I updated the answer to give you something else to explore with if you chose.  a possible option for mobile.

Comment: Also, if you are satisfied with my answer, please select it as correct :)

Comment: yes definitely, i am satisfied and happy with you answer. i have marked it as answer, thanks again, you saved my night :-)

Comment: Hi Adam, one of my friend just checked his city is Akron, my state is Ohio, I live in the Country of United States. but the ip-api is giving his location as Romulus , which is incorrect ?? Please advice..

Comment: I believe that is based on your ISP.  I usually don't have a problem with it.  But it ip addresses -> city arent dead on accurate all the time.  

Have your friend try this and see if it still gives him romulus.
http://www.infosniper.net/

Also, Check out a front end method using javascript again.  http://html5demos.com/geo

You can click "view source" To see how its done.

Comment: But this javascript is asking user permission, can you  please check the following site for which we are working, whether it is giving you correct location, http://www.strong-finance-daily.com

Comment: Was on lunch, just got this,

Yes, I just checked it, where is it displaying the location?  You are welcome to email me so we can move this conversation.

adam.ncmich.edu@gmail.com

Comment: Yes i see it .  it says "Petoskey Mom Makes $8000 ... "  Do you have an email?  I have some ideas for your website i think you would like.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Petoskey is the correct location for me.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze - Thanks for the great answer. But this seems to have a dependency on this site http://ip-api.com. Any other mechanism without dependency pls?

Answer (score 5):

JSON can also be used, because [Serialized PHP endpoint](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php) is deprecated.

> Deprecated
>   Use JSON. Almost all PHP sites now support json_decode(), and it's faster than unserialize()

```
function get_ip_detail($ip){
   $ip_response = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$ip);
   $ip_array=json_decode($ip_response);
   return  $ip_array;
 }

 $user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $ip_array= get_ip_detail($user_ip);
 echo $country_name=$ip_array->country; 
 echo $city=$ip_array->city;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to pay for an API or be bound by ridiculous rate limits. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use any API service to get the city and state information for an IP address. For example, to get the city name and state name for an IP address using IP2Location.io,

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.ip2location.io/?' . http_build_query([
    'ip'      => '8.8.8.8',
    'key'     => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'format'  => 'json',
    'lang'    => 'en',
]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response_array = json_decode($response, true);
echo 'City Name: ' . $response_array["city_name"];
echo 'State Name: ' . $response_array["region_name"];
```